# Biztalk message level security among different applications under same Biztalk group

Tags: biztalk

There are two applications A and B under the same Biztalk group (reading the same BiztalkMsgDB)

Is it possible to set the application A cannot get (from sendport/orchestration etc) the message received from application B?

It is the prevent Biztalk support of application A set the sendport filter wrongly such that it gets the messages received from application B.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to administratively enforce any boundaries between applications running on the same BizTalk Group.

However, because mis-subscribing, either accidentally or intentionally, requries Administrative provledges anyway, the risk is really a user problem, not a technical one.